# Is "as she insisted her name was" okay?

Tags: phrase-choice

Everybody knew that her real name was Merry, but she kept telling everyone that her name was Mariot.

Now, 176 years later, I am writing memoirs and mention her in them:

> "Merry (or Mariot, as she insisted her name was) was a very funny
>   girl..."

Can I really say here "as she insisted her name was" or it sounds weird in English? Should it be like "as she insisted on how she was to be called" or, perhaps, just "as she insisted"?

Also, do I need to put Mariot in quotation marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's grammatical and idiomatic.  You could also say simply "as she insisted" since it would be understood that name was the topic.

> Merry (or Mariot, as she insisted) was a very funny girl...

You could also say

... as she insisted on being called

Comment: I see. Thank you. So the quotation marks are not needed, right?

Comment: That is simply a matter of typographical convention.  You can tell your editor to f..k off if he or she insists on placing the name in quotation marks, or conversely refuses to let you use them.